# Get node id from a grid view

Tags: views, 8

I am new with D8

I have a view which lists some content about a specific content type.

I made a plugin that permit to add a custom drop button for each view rows

This button has to make some control and then redirect to a new content type or form.

This part is OK

But

I would like to know how is it possible, in the button context, I can get the node_id of the specific content :

the button in first row will return the node_id of content of row 1
the button in second row will return the node_id of content of row 2
...

Comment: thanks, and how i can get the field in the plugin source code please

Answer (score 1):

so after several hours i found the good solution !
Simple solution for people not new like me on drupal. lol

In my view I added the field "Content:id" of my content_type
And checked "Exclude from display"

In my plugin .php file in the method render(ResultRow $row) i got the famous id like this :

```
$nid = $this->getEntity($row)->id();
```

that's all !!